# My pi calculation using Liebniz doesn't work and I don't understand why

Tags: java

Why does this code generate the result 4.0?

```
public class Liebniz1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double piOverFour = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) 
                piOverFour = piOverFour + 1 / (1 + 2 * i);
            else 
                piOverFour = piOverFour - 1 / (1 + 2 * i);
        } // for

        System.out.println("Liebniz calculated pi to: " + 4 * piOverFour);
    }
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where have you narrowed the problem down to?

Comment: You do know that Pi is unsolvable correct [source](https://nrich.maths.org/2490) - sorry, I couldnt resist! :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Explanation:* `1 / (1 + 2 * i)` is `1` for `i=0`, that means `piOverFour` will be `1` after the first iteration.
`1 / (1 + 2 * i)` will always be `0` for `i > 0` due to integer division.
That means `piOverFour` will always remain `1` => `4 * piOverFour` will always be `4`.

*Solution:* Use `1.0 / (1 + 2 * i)` to circumvent integer division.